# Share Internet on the same interface OS X

Tags: macos, share, alias, ifconfig

I have a laptop with only one Ethernet port and I connect to the internet through it using DHCP to get my IP. I also have a LAN which needs to connect to the Internet. The ONLY way to achieve this is using the laptop's Ethernet port.

I created an alias for en0 and allowed me to connect to the LAN.

The problem would be how to share the Internet using the same Ethernet port from the DHCP IP(which I set up using the Network Settings) to the alias(different IP) for the LAN. Again both IPs are on the same physical interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set up a separate IP network space, add a secondary address to your ethernet interface, and run natd on your laptop to translate and route between the networks.
(of course putting all your other devices on the secondary network).